# Displaying a menu/block in a page/node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm new to Drupal and making some changes to an exisiting site.

I have a page with a menu in the left side bar, which shows on all the pages in that menu apart from the one i've added. I've done it before where you have to add the URL of the page you want the menu to show somewhere in the admin panel for the menu to show.

If i go to: site building > blocks > block_name and then tick 'Users cannot control whether or not they see this block.' The menu wil show. But it will also show on pages I don't want it to.

Do you know where in the Admin I need to go to allow the menu to show on this new page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of hunting around I've found the answer, the block has text box at the bottom of the page 'page specific settings' where you add the URL of the page you wish the block to show on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.

It creates the menu inside a block and treats it EXACTLY like a block.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.